# retrieve data after successful paypal payment in magento

Tags: jquery, magento, jquery-mobile, paypal

I have sample product in my magento store implementing as a mobile application , when i Purchase the product using Paypal express checkout method, after the successful payment how to retrieve the information like order Id, Address and so on.

I don't Know how to retrieve the data, after successful Paypal payment at the same time I want to store the purchase information in my magento store there is any API available or how can I do that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Pay-pal provides you with IPN (Instant payment notification) if you are using an hidden field and submitting the required data just pass in an hidden field with `name=NotifyURL` and `url="yoursite.com/function"`.

This particular `url / function` will be notified whenever an payment is `made / initiated`, IPN even works with connection loss or other such problems. Using  IPN is best practice for paypal express-checkout.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly backend logic and belongs inside your Magento store and not to the endusers browser! Don't try to solve your problem with JavaScript/jQuery. Search for a solution in PHP instead.

PayPal offers a nice REST API https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

There are examples to use the API with JavaScript. But those are provided for usage on a node.js server! Have a look at the PHP examples or google for PayPal integration in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding does Magento already this. When someone pays with PayPal or any other gateway via magento the payment information should be automatically stored and visible in the dashboard. I would recommend going over their articles in their KB. [Here is one on how to set up Paypal Express Checkout](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-express-checkout-for-magento-community#step4).

In the article that I just linked it states that in Advanced Settings you can select "Require Customer's Billing Address". If this is set to yes, your customers will have to set their address, which in return will be logged by Magento when the payment is finished.

If this is not the answer you're looking for I would recommend looking into their [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/), which would allow you to fetch the success query. You can find example code on how to use their API for most languages on PayPal's GitHub.